# SQLalchemy fails after version 1.4.15 to connect to SQL Server

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a python script which has worked fine, but if I upgrade SQLalchemy to a version newer than 1.4.15 (or that is the last working I have) then I get the error:

sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

My connection in python looks like this:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


#Create connection to SQL
NAV = 'mssql://<server>/<database>?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=yes'
engine = create_engine(NAV, fast_executemany=True)
```

If I downgrade SQLalchemy to 1.4.15 it works just fine again.

Any ideas as I would like not to be stuck on an old version forever :-)

Comment: remove the `?trusted_connection=yes` from the end of your connection URI

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes I have updated my entire Conda environment and only downgraded the SQLalchemy package. So unless PYODBC is affected by the SQLalchemy package then it is the same.

Comment: @GordThompson - if I do that won't I then have to put in credentials instead of single sign on?

Comment: `Trusted_Connection=yes` tells the server to use "Windows Authentication" (Windows login on Windows clients, or Kerberos on Linux). Newer versions of the ODBC driver (including "SQL Server Native Client 11.0") will default to that setting if they do not receive a UID and PWD as part of the connection string. So, in essence, the `trusted_connection=yes` in your connection string wasn't doing anything, anyway.

Comment: @GordThompson - holy cow, that was it! Thanks a lot for your explanation, it both solved my problem and made the syntax more simple!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLAlchemy 1.4.16 fixed a long-standing but subtle bug in the parsing of connection URIs. Previous versions would accept

```
…/dbname?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=yes
```

and essentially ignore anything after (and including) the second `?`. Now SQLAlchemy requires that subsequent (2nd, 3rd, …) arguments be separated with `&`, not `?`, so the "driver=" is being interpreted as

```
SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=yes
```

instead of just

```
SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0
```

and the former (with '+' unescaped to space) does not match any known ODBC driver name.

As noted in the comments to the question, the fix is to simply omit the `?trusted_connection=yes` part since it is not needed anyway.